# How to create a memory dump of a Mac OS Application

Tags: macos, security, process, operating-system, dump

How can I create a memory dump of a process under Mac OS? 
--> dump all occupied memory of a process into a file for analysis.

Answer (score 10):

You might need to disable system integrity protection for this to work - beware that this is a security risk and you should re-enable after you are done.

- restart into Recovery Mode,
- `csrutil disable` via the terminal
- restart

In your new session, run 'top', find your process ID.

```
lldb --attach-pid <PID>
process save-core "filename"
```

Restart into recovery, and reenable system integrity protection.

Comment: Never reenable system integrity protection

Comment: On MacOS 11.5.1 it was not necessary to disable system integrity protection.